# phpで時間が9時間ずれます

Tags: php

htmlにphpを埋め込む形で使用しているのですが、

```
<?php
$time = new DateTime();
echo $time->format('H:i:s');
?>
```

このように現在時刻を表示させると、実際の日本時間より9時間遅れてしまいます。
標準時が表示されてしまっているのかと思い、php.iniのタイムゾーン設定も確認しましたが、もともとAsia/Tokyoになっていました。
また、DateTimeのコンストラクタの第二引数に new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo') を指定しても結果は変わりません。
ではタイムゾーンにUTCを設定してみたらどうなるのか試してみたら、もともと遅れていた9時間に時差が合わさったようで、18時間も遅れてしまいました。

どうすれば正しい日本時間を表示できるのでしょうか？分かる方いらっしゃればどうかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちらで試してみた所では`$time = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));` で問題無く表示されました。内部時計がずれている（つまり他の標準時になっている）ということはないですか？

Comment: タイムゾーンの件について既に記載されているので、別口の疑問。。。そのサーバのOSなど、環境はどうなっていますか？コマンドが打てるならLinuxなら「`date`」、Windowsなら「`echo %date% %time%`」など打って意図通りの時刻が出ますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

お二人のコメントのおかげで解決しましたので報告いたします。

コメント頂いた通り、phpの問題ではなくOSの問題でした。(centOSを使ってます)
`hwclock --show --debug`というコマンドを打ってみると、ハードウェアクロックにはUTC時間が入っているのにローカルの時間が入っていると見なされていたことがわかりました。なので、etc/adjtimeの`LOCAL`を`UTC`に書き直し、`hwclock --hctosys`でシステムクロックを同期してみたら直りました。

これが正しい解決方法なのかはわかりませんが、一応phpからでもちゃんと日本時間が表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございます。